# Finding $\sup$ of $\{\sqrt{n} - \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor | n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

The question is to find $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $B=\{\sqrt{n} - \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor | n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is defined as the largest integer that is smaller than $x$.

That $\inf B=0$ is trivial, I'm having troubles with the other side though. I think intuitively that $\sup B=1$ and random calculations seems to confirm it since I can get as many 9's after the dot as I want by calculating $\sqrt{10^{2n}-1}$ for increasingly large values of $n$, but apart from that I have no idea how to get specific values or even know if a value is sufficient for a given $\epsilon$.

Any hints on where to go with such proofs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** If $n=k^2+a$ where $0 \leq a <2k+1$ then
$$ \sqrt{n}-\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor=\sqrt{n}-k=\frac{n-k^2}{\sqrt{n}+k}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}+k}\geq \frac{a}{(k+1)+k}= \frac{a}{2k+1}$$

Now it is easy to chose $k$ and $0 \leq a \leq 2k$  such that $\frac{a}{2k+1}$ becomes arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: Well that's a really nice way of doing it. Didn't think about breaking the number into easier to manage numbers ><

Comment: Hi @N. S. how can one show that $[\sqrt{n^2-1}]=n-1$? Thanks!

Comment: @user726608 Since $n-1$ is an integer, you need to show that $n-1 \leq \sqrt{n^2-1} <n$.

Comment: @N. S. Then we get that $\sqrt{n^2-1}=n-1$ so $[\sqrt{n^2-1}]=n-1$ right? For the inequality you wrote it is enough to take the square power of it (it is a trivial inequality though)?

Comment: @user726608 No, $\sqrt{n^2-1}$ is definitely not $n-1$, unless $n=1$. Yes the given inequalities are easy to solve, and then you need to look at the definition of integral part.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to compute this limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{(n+1)^2-1}-n\right)$$

If you don't know about limits, just write

$$\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt{(n+1)^2-1}-n\right)&\cdot\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^2-1}+n}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2-1}+n}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)^2-1-n^2}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2-1}+n}\\
&=\frac{2n}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}+n}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{1+\frac2n}+1}
\end{align}$$

Note that the term $2/n$ becomes arbitrarily small as $n$ increases (informally speaking).

Comment: We haven't actually learned limits yet so I'm not sure how to use this, but it seems to be going to 1? no idea how to prove it though.

Comment: hmm I understand that, still not sure how to use it though :P